# How to make a new JButton instance in a existing button group everytime a Jbutton is pressed(clicked)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

This may come off as an odd question, but I would like to make a program that makes a new Jbutton instance in an existing group every time a button(called new) is pressed. It will be added under the previously added button, all buttons must be part of a group(so when one button is pressed it will deselect previously selected button if the button in the group is pressed) and should be able to make an infinite number of buttons given n number of clicks. Here is what I have so far, but honestly I don't even know how to approach this one.

```
public static void makebuttonpane() {
    buttonpane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();

    nbutton = new JButton("New");

    d.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    buttonpane.add(nbutton,d);
    nbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonMaker());
    //d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

}

public static void addbutton(JButton button) {
    System.out.println("button made");
    buttonpane.removeAll();
    nbutton = new JButton("New");

    d.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    buttonpane.add(nbutton,d);
    nbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonMaker());

    d.gridx=0;
    System.out.println(ButtonMaker.getNumb());
    d.gridy= ButtonMaker.getNumb();

    buttonpane.add(button,d);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    buttonpane.validate();
}

public static void makebuttonpane() {
    buttonpane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();

    nbutton = new JButton("New");

    d.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    buttonpane.add(nbutton,d);
    nbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonMaker());
    //d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

}

public static void addbutton(JButton button) {
    System.out.println("button made");
    buttonpane.removeAll();
    nbutton = new JButton("New");

    d.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    buttonpane.add(nbutton,d);
    nbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonMaker());

    d.gridx=0;
    System.out.println(ButtonMaker.getNumb());
    d.gridy= ButtonMaker.getNumb();

    buttonpane.add(button,d);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    buttonpane.validate();
}

class ButtonMaker implements ActionListener{
public static int i=1;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("I hear you");
    //System.out.println(i);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button "+i);
    MultiListener.addbutton(button);
    i++;

}
public static int getNumb() {
    return i;
}
```

}

It adds the first button instance but pressing 'New' only changes that first created button instead of making a new one underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a GUI that adds a JButton when you click on the "Add Button" button.

[image: JButton Creator GUI]

Feel free to modify this any way you want.

Mainly, I separated the construction of the JFrame, the construction of the JPanel, and the action listener.  Focusing on one part at a time, I was able to code and test this GUI quickly.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JButtonCreator implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JButtonCreator());
    }

    private static int buttonCount = 0;

    private JButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButton Creator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonPanel = new JButtonPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                buttonPanel.getPanel());

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class JButtonPanel {

        private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;

        private JPanel buttonPanel;
        private JPanel panel;

        public JButtonPanel() {
            createPartControl();
        }

        private void createPartControl() {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));

            buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

            panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton newButton = new JButton("Add Button");
            newButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
            panel.add(newButton, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        }

        public void addJButton() {
            String text = "Button " + ++buttonCount;
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            buttonPanel.add(button);
            buttonGroup.add(button);
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private JButtonPanel buttonPanel;

        public ButtonListener(JButtonPanel buttonPanel) {
            this.buttonPanel = buttonPanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            buttonPanel.addJButton();
            buttonPanel.getPanel().revalidate();;
        }

    }

}
```